# Python scrape all javascript mailto

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I need to scrape a website that has emails displaying as 'email'. When you click the hyperlink it automatically opens your email and has a new message with said email ready to send.

I thought i could just go through the html and scrape the email out. However the email are listed as a javascript object (which i'm unfamiliar).

the email is coded as:

```
<li class="email"><a href='javascript:let("179 540 458 268 179 597 380 355 635 44 188 274",649,387)'>email</a></li>
```

I am trying to figure out how to extract and decode this into a regular email format.

Comment: is the website public?

Comment: Yes its a public website

Comment: can you share the url and your current code please? Also indicate the expected output.

Comment: https://barrowjackson.yourkwoffice.com/mcj/user/AssociateSearchSubmitAction.do?orgId=5555&firstName=&lastName=&rows=100

Comment: there is a hyperlink of email for each of the entries; and i want to extract that email to input into a list

Answer (score 0):

The page uses obfuscation via a series of javascript functions. The code is copyrighted so I am unsure of the legabilities of coding it across into python which is pretty trivial. The code is located here: https://barrowjackson.yourkwoffice.com/mcj/template_content/scripts/deobscure.js

The author has a website but I doubt that will say "sure you can write your own version of this in a different language"....

You can also easily map out the characters into your own lookup dictionary as the relevant character set is not large. When you click on a link you can see the decoded value in the network traffic.

You only need the first argument of the function call you see in the actual page e.g.

```
let("179 540 458 268 179 597 380 355 635 44 188 274",649,387)
```

Grab the first argument: "179 540 458 268 179 597 380 355 635 44 188 274" and translate that.